# Difference between values in the same column between max and min dates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Help with MS SQL query needed. I need to display the difference between two values in the same column where data is between max and min date. For example if I have the following table:

[see details behind the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tUlb.jpg)

```
location|   date        |amount
------- |   -------     |-------
1000    |   2016-01-01  |400
1000    |   2016-01-04  |600    
1000    |   2016-01-05  |650
1000    |   2016-01-06  |820
1000    |   2016-01-18  |850
1000    |   2016-01-22  |900
1000    |   2016-01-28  |910
1000    |   2016-01-31  |950
2000    |   2016-01-07  |100
2000    |   2016-01-13  |150
2000    |   2016-01-15  |260
2000    |   2016-01-20  |330
```

The output should be as follow:

```
location|   difference
------- |   -------
1000    |   550
2000    |   230
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 3):

You can as the below:

```
SELECT
   location,
   MAX(Amount) - MIN(Amount) difference
FROM
  Tbl
GROUP BY
  location
```

Updated

```
SELECT
    T.location,
    Maxv.Amount - Minv.Amount as difference
FROM
(
    SELECT
       location,
       MIN(date) MinDate,
       MAX(date) MaxDate
    FROM
      Tbl A 
    GROUP BY
      location
) T INNER JOIN 
Tbl Minv ON T.MinDate = Minv.date AND T.location = Minv.location INNER JOIN 
Tbl Maxv ON T.MaxDate= Maxv.date AND T.location = Maxv.location
```

Comment: Thanks NEER. Just to be more specific, looking for a difference in amount between minimun and maximun dates, not minimum and maximum amounts.

Answer (score 1):

It is a classic `top-n-per-group` problem, where you need to get not just `top`, but also `bottom` value per group.

One standard way to achieve it without self-joins is by using `ROW_NUMBER`. In your case there will be two sets of numbers: ordered ascending and descending.

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (location int, dt date, Amount int);
INSERT INTO @T (location, dt, Amount ) VALUES
(1000,'2016-01-01',400),
(1000,'2016-01-04',600),
(1000,'2016-01-05',650),
(1000,'2016-01-06',820),
(1000,'2016-01-18',850),
(1000,'2016-01-22',900),
(1000,'2016-01-28',910),
(1000,'2016-01-31',950),
(2000,'2016-01-07',100),
(2000,'2016-01-13',150),
(2000,'2016-01-15',260),
(2000,'2016-01-20',330);
```

**Query**

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        location
        ,dt
        ,Amount
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY location ORDER BY dt ASC) AS rnAsc
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY location ORDER BY dt DESC) AS rnDesc
    FROM @T
)
SELECT
    location
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN rnAsc = 1 THEN -Amount ELSE Amount END) AS diff
FROM CTE
WHERE
    rnAsc = 1
    OR rnDesc = 1
GROUP BY location
ORDER BY location;
```

**Result**

```
+----------+------+
| location | diff |
+----------+------+
|     1000 |  550 |
|     2000 |  230 |
+----------+------+
```

To understand how it works run just the query inside the CTE at first and examine the intermediate results.

The main query simply groups by `location` and calculates the `SUM` of two values. `CASE` expression changes the sign of the first value to get the difference.

If it is possible to have a location with just one row, the result would be negative `Amount`. As if it is a difference between 0 and the only available `Amount` value. If you want to get some other result in this case, please clarify the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN TRAN

CREATE TABLE #Details(_Location VARCHAR(100),_Date DATE,Amount INT)
CREATE TABLE #Diff(Location VARCHAR(100),_MinDate DATE,_MaxDate DATE,Amount1 INT,Amount2 INT)

INSERT INTO #Details(_Location ,_Date ,Amount )
SELECT 1000,'2016-01-01',400 UNION ALL
SELECT 1000,'2016-01-04',600 UNION ALL
SELECT 1000,'2016-01-05',650 UNION ALL
SELECT 1000,'2016-01-06',820 UNION ALL
SELECT 1000,'2016-01-18',850 UNION ALL
SELECT 1000,'2016-01-22',900 UNION ALL
SELECT 1000,'2016-01-28',910 UNION ALL
SELECT 1000,'2016-01-31',950 UNION ALL
SELECT 2000,'2016-01-07',100 UNION ALL
SELECT 2000,'2016-01-13',150 UNION ALL
SELECT 2000,'2016-01-15',260 UNION ALL
SELECT 2000,'2016-01-20',330 


INSERT INTO  #Diff (Location ,_MinDate ,_MaxDate)
SELECT _Location , MIN(_Date) _MinDate, MAX(_Date) _MaxDate
FROM #Details
GROUP BY _Location


UPDATE #Diff SET Amount1 = Amount
FROM #Details
WHERE _Date = _MaxDate AND _Location = Location

UPDATE #Diff SET Amount2 = Amount
FROM #Details
WHERE _Date = _MinDate AND _Location = Location

SELECT Location , ( Amount1 - Amount2 ) [Difference]
FROM #Diff

ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

Easy & Short Query:

```
DECLARE @loc_tbl TABLE( location INT, loc_date DATE,amount INT)
INSERT INTO @loc_tbl VALUES('1000','2016-01-01','400'),
('1000','2016-01-04','600'),('1000','2016-01-05','650'),
('1000','2016-01-06','820'),('1000','2016-01-18','850'),
('1000','2016-01-22','900'),('1000','2016-01-28','910'),
('1000','2016-01-31','950'),('2000','2016-01-07','100'),
('2000','2016-01-13','150'),('2000','2016-01-15','260'),
('2000','2016-01-20','330')

SELECT A.location,(B.amount-C.amount) amt_difference FROM ( SELECT location,
MAX(loc_Date) maximum,MIN(loc_Date) minimum FROM @loc_tbl GROUP BY location ) A
LEFT JOIN @loc_tbl B ON B.loc_date = A.maximum
LEFT JOIN @loc_tbl C ON C.loc_date = A.minimum
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Your welcome, please mark it as correct if it worked for you, so that other people could get a reference to the correct answer. :) @Jasu

Answer (score 0):

Below is the Table(Name: MyTab)

```
  Location  dt      amount
    1000    2014-06-01  90
    1000    2014-09-01  40
    1000    2014-10-01  100
    1000    2015-06-01  900
    1000    2015-12-01  907
    2000    2004-11-22  432
    2000    2010-11-22  709
    2000    2014-11-01  922
    2000    2014-11-22  728
    2000    2015-11-01  907
    2000    2015-12-01  907
    2000    2016-11-22  553
```

Below is the Query

```
;WITH CTE
AS(
SELECT location,min(dt) mindt,max(dt) maxdt from MyTab group by location
)
SELECT c.location,max(m.amount)-min(m.amount) amt from cte c 
INNER JOIN MyTab m on c.location = m.location and (c.mindt = m.dt or c.maxdt = m.dt )
GROUP BY c.location
```

Output is

```
location amt
1000    817
2000    121
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (location int, dt date, Amount int);
INSERT INTO @T (location, dt, Amount ) VALUES
(1000,'2016-01-01',400),
(1000,'2016-01-04',600),
(1000,'2016-01-05',650),
(1000,'2016-01-06',820),
(1000,'2016-01-18',850),
(1000,'2016-01-22',900),
(1000,'2016-01-28',910),
(1000,'2016-01-31',950),
(2000,'2016-01-07',100),
(2000,'2016-01-13',150),
(2000,'2016-01-15',260),
(2000,'2016-01-20',540);


 with cte as (select location,first_value (amount)OVER(partition by location order by dt desc)v1
,last_value(amount) OVER (partition by location order by (select NULL))as v2
from @T
)
select distinct(location),v1-v2 from cte
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.